# Failed to build and deploy Next.js app to vercel : ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Empty dependency (no request)

Tags: webpack, build, compiler-errors, next.js

When I try to build my Next App and deploy to Vercel, I get this error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Empty dependency (no request)**

Next version : 11
Webpack version: 5

What I've tried:

- deleted node_modules then used the command yarn install.
- created a new Next App (reused old component files and config)
- corrected and disable some eslint rules
- updated the webpack
  config with babel-loader

This hasn't worked. What should I do to correct this error ?

**Error:**

```
    yarn run v1.22.5
$ next build
info  - Loaded env from D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\.env.local
info  - Loaded env from D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\.env.production
info  - Loaded env from D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Empty dependency (no request)


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:397:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (D:\FIV\nextjs-fiv-3\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:77:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I do not know how to debug this as there is not a clear error that I can understand.

**Here is my next.config.js file**

```
 const path = require('path')

require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = { 


    env: {
        API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
        IMAGES_DOMAIN: process.env.IMAGES_DOMAIN,
        CLOUDINARY_NAME: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
        AWS_IMAGES_DOMAIN: process.env.AWS_IMAGES_DOMAIN,
    },

    images: {
        deviceSizes: [640, 768, 1024, 1280, 1600],
        imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
        domains: [process.env.IMAGES_DOMAIN_NAME, process.env.AWS_IMAGES_DOMAIN_NAME],
        path: '/_next/image',
        loader: 'default',
    },

    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.resolve.alias['components'] = path.join(__dirname, 'components')
        config.resolve.alias['public'] = path.join(__dirname, 'public')
        use: [
            options.defaultLoaders.babel,
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [
                  ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
                ]
              }
            },
          ]
        return config
    },
```

**Package.json file:**

```
    {
  "name": "nextjs-fiv-3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap --config next-custom-sitemap.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.19",
    "@rebass/forms": "^4.0.6",
    "@storyofams/next-password-protect": "^1.5.11",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
    "@types/next": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "emotion-theming": "^11.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "magic-sdk": "^6.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-i18next": "^8.8.0",
    "next-seo": "^4.26.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.6.168",
    "next-with-apollo": "^5.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.2",
    "polished": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-chartist": "^0.14.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hooks-helper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.7",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-query": "^3.23.2",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "reflexbox": "^4.0.6",
    "uikit": "^3.7.3",
    "webpack": "^5.52.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
It was in one of my Next App pages. I had to remove unused modules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).